# Lots of hits from 173.252.103.3

Tags: iis-7

Just wondering if any of you experiencing lots of hits from 173.252.103.3. 
When I do an IP Trace it tracks to Facebook.

http://www.ip-tracker.org/lookup/whois-lookup.php?query=173.252.103.3

Why is Facebook hitting my sites 400

Comment: What is being hit, what is that 400, how did you observe that, do you have logfiles etc. If you expect a helpful answer you must give more information. If you see this in your IIS logfiles, then what referrer is being given for instance? Maybe someone just shared a link pointing to your website.

Comment: IT hits random links, a URL. In IIS logs, in Google Analytic, and on error logs.

Comment: If someone shared, shouldn't it just be 1 request to 1 url? It seems that the ~400 requests are requesting the same url.

Comment: You really need to ask facebook, all we can do is guess.

Answer (score 1):

Could easily just be a simple bot-net node on an infected computer within the FB company.  Especially if link attempts seem random.

Comment: anyway to report to facebook?

Comment: Probably not worth your time... I imagine that, like me, they've set up a separate wifi network for guests and visitors on a separate public IP.  In that case, the computer may not even be theirs... Just hooked to an IP they own.